# How to count each rows ID of tables relationship using laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

so I have a 5 tables in my database with **pivot**, **`Countries, Cities, Shops, Users, shop_employee`** their relationship is this

```
Countries  | Cities      | Shops     | shop_employees| Users 
 id        | country_id  | city_id   |  shop_id      | id
                                        employee_id
```

my goal is I want to count each **City, shop, employees** in the Country

this is my controller

```
class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function country(){
       $countries = Country::with(['cities.shops.employees'])->get();
       return view('country',['countries'=>$countries]);
    }
}
```

this is my model **Country**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
}
```

this is my model **City**

```
class City extends Model
{
    public function shops(){
        return $this->hasMany(Shop::class);
    }
}
```

this is my model **Shops**

```
class Shop extends Model
{
    public function employees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'shop_employees','shop_id','employee_id');
    }
}
```

this is my view

```
        <table class="table-fixed">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300">Country</th>
                    <th class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300">City</th>
                    <th class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300">Shop</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($countries as $country)
                <tr >
                    <td class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300">{{ $country->name }}</td>
                    <td class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300">{{ $country->cities->count() }}</td>
                    <td class="py-2 px-2 border border-gray-300"></td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I tried this code its working fine  the **City** is counting

```
{{ $country->cities->count() }}
```

the output, in this output I want to display the count of **shops** and **employee**

[image]

but when im trying this code it gives me a error

```
  $country->cities->shops->count() or
  $country->cities->shops->employees->count()
```

error: `Property [shops] does not exist on this collection instance`

Comment: Change it to `Country::with(['cities', 'shops', 'employees'])->get();` instead

Comment: did you mean like this? `Country::with(['cities','cities.shops', 'cities.shops.employees'])->get()`

Comment: still not working even i tried that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `addSelect` method
Using subquery and passing a closure

```
Country::withCount('cities as city_count')
  ->addSelect([
    'shop_count' => Shop::selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->whereIn(
      'city_id',
       City::select('id')->whereColumn('country_id','countries.id'))
    ->limit(1), 
  ])
  ->addSelect([
    'employee_count' => DB::table('shop_employees')->selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->whereIn(
    'shop_id',
     Shop::select('id')
         ->whereIn(
           'city_id',
            City::select('id')->whereColumn('country_id','countries.id')
          )
     )->limit(1), 
  ])
  ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for another solution. but i already fine the solution i want to see                                                     `$countries = Country::with([
        'cities' =>fn($query) => $query->withCount('shops'),
        'cities.shops' => fn($query) => $query->withCount('employees')
    ])
   ->withCount('cities')
   ->get();`

Comment: Welcome but my solution is good for you it's faster query than another solution

Comment: yes you are right your solutions is a better and gold it's showing fast the list of counts each tables, but i don't have a `employee::selectRow` model only have **users** , **shop** model has a pivot table shop_employee with user table. this code it's working i cut some addelect  `Country::withCount('cities as city_count')
  ->addSelect([
    'shop_count' => Shop::selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->whereIn(
      'city_id',
       City::select('id')->whereColumn('country_id','countries.id'))
    ->limit(1), 
  ])->get()`  this working good but the total employees not showing

Comment: you can you db facade class i updated my answer

Comment: thank you so much for editing, your answer such a unique and less querying when it comes to other table to loop

Answer (score 3):

You can try to get the aggregate with the query itself

```php
class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function country(){
        $countries = Country::with([
            'cities' => fn($query) => $query->withCount('shops'),
            'cities.shops' => fn($query) => $query->withCount('employees'),
            'cities.shops.employees'
        ])
       ->withCount('cities')
       ->get();

       return view('country',['countries'=>$countries]);
    }
}
```

Then you can access the aggregate values as

```
//Get the count of cities under the country
$country->cities_count; 

foreach($countries as $country) {
    $noOfCities = $country->cities_count;

    $noOfShops = $country->cities->sum('shops_count');

    $noOfEmployees = $country->cities->reduce(
        fn($carry, $city) => $carry + $city->shops->sum('employees_count')
    );
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Aggregating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models)

Comment: it gives me on the `Call to undefined method App\Models\City::cities()`
this line showing error `'cities' => fn($query) => $query->withCount('cities'),`

Comment: @RayParas Sorry my bad. Have updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: thank you, you give me idea i changed somethings in that code 

`$countries = Country::with([
        'cities' =>fn($query) => $query->withCount('shops'),
        'cities.shops' => fn($query) => $query->withCount('employees')
    ])
   ->withCount('cities')
   ->get();`

Comment: Ha ha yeah. Messed up with `->withCount()` placements. Have updated answer to fix it